Outlook deleting internet headers (smtp headers) from inbox
While sending mail we add bcc recipient and internet message header (smtp header X-Custom-Header). Once the mail is sent we can see the header in send folder copy of mail but it is removed from the inbox copy of bcc recipient. Any thoughts how we can retain header for bcc recipient as well.
Note: we are adding header via Aspose Library https://docs.aspose.com/email/java/

Is the message being sent through the Outlook Object Model? What exactly (whcih MAPI property) are you seeing in the Sent Items folder?
